# Render method not getting called in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unr4s3jd9qA) guide to add Firebase Authentication to my React.js web app. But the redirection when the user is already logged in is not working properly.

App:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <PrivateRoute exact path={pathNames.teamList} component={TeamList} />
          <Route exact path={pathNames.login} component={PhoneLogin} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```

Private Route:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    // <Route exact path={!!currentUser ? pathNames.teamList : pathNames.login} />
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={routeProps => {
        console.log("Props: ", routeProps);
        return !!currentUser ? (
          <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={pathNames.login} />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

`useContext` gives me the value of current user.

If I remove `{...rest}` in `Route`, then it kind of works. The path is still `/login`, but I can see 2 components: 1) Team List and 2) Login below it. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
pathNames.teamList = "\"
pathNames.login = "\login"
```

well.. if you are removing `{...rest}`, then you are not using `exact` prop for the Private route anymore. so you have to `path` and `exact` explicitly to the Route, in order to make it work.

If you dont use `exact`, it will take te default path `"\"` and render the component on every route. so you will see `TeamList` component in every route, even after logged out.

```
<Route
      exact
      path="\"
      render={routeProps => {
        console.log("Props: ", routeProps);
        return !!currentUser ? (
          <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={pathNames.login} />
        );
      }}
    />
```

Also exact won't be needed everywhere.

```
 <Route path={pathNames.login} component={PhoneLogin} />
```

Comment: what is not working.. can you share your code full code.. then.. on codesandbox.com